# How can I return int[,] inside a method?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating a game with the use of C# XNA.
I have a TileMap stored in an `int[,]`array like this:

```cpp
    int[,] Map = 
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };
```

I'm curious on how I could accept this type of array `Map[,]` by my classes constructor and even in methods if possible and return the array?

I want to return an `int[,]` just like this:

```
    public int[,] GetMap()
    {
        return 
    int[,] Map1 = 
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What did you try? What was the error?

Comment: Read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
public int[,] GetMap()
{
    return new [,] 
    {
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };
}
```

also can be:

```
public int[,] GetMap()
{
    int [,] map = new [,]
    {
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Method(int[,] map)
{
    // use map here
}

int[,] MethodWithReturn()
{
    // create Map here
    return Map;
}
```

Comment: How could I return the array?

Comment: @user1376460 Errr... have you tried `return Map;`? What have you tried and what problems are you having? Please post your code and the error message you get.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question.

Comment: Try that with int first. You have error with basic understanding of Return statement.

Comment: I wanted to return it without instancising it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[,] GetMap()
{
    int[,] map = new int[,]
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };

    return map;
}
```

You can't use implicit declaration with multidimensional arrays, so you need to declare the array first, then return it.

Comment: Maybe you're correct. I know for a fact you can't use var in this manner, but maybe return is allowed.

Comment: You don't have to believe me. Just test it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do:

```
return new int[,]
           {
               {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
               {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
               {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
           };
```

But if you're asking about how would you handle the int[,] from outside, when you don't know the bounds... Then:

```
private static int[,] CreateMap(out int height)
{
    height = 3;

    return new int[,]
               {
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
               };
}
```

Usage from outside:

```
int height;
int[,] map = CreateMap(out height);

int width = map.Length / height;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(map[i, j]);
    }
}
```